# What is the use of multiple control endpoints (non-EP0)?

Tags: usb

I learned on [OSDev wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Universal_Serial_Bus) that Endpoint 0 is the default control pipe, allowing for bi-directional control transfers. This is used for device configuration, e.g. to retrieve device descriptors. The [USB 2.0 spec](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/usb20_docs/) explains this more thorougly in section 5.5 *Control Transfers*.

There are also a limited amount of endpoints available (2 for low-speed, 15 for full- and high-speed devices). Somewhere in the USB 2.0 spec, I have read that there must be *at least one* control pipe. This implies that there may be multiple control endpoints, but what is the use of it? Do you know any particular USB device or class that has an EP configured as control pipe?

---

Later, I found this in the spec, section 10.1.2 *Control Mechanisms*:

> A particular USB device may allow the use of additional message pipes
>   to transfer device-specific control information. These pipes use the
>   same communications protocol as the default pipe, but the information
>   transferred is specific to the USB device and is not standardized by
>   the USB Specification.

If I understand it correctly, this means that non-EP0 cannot be used to configure the device (say, a standard request such as `GET_DESCRIPTOR`). But the setup/data/status stages seem still to be available ("[..] use the same communications protocol [..]"). Is this correct? Or is the use of standard/class requests forbidden for non-EP0?

Background: while working on an emulated USB device in QEMU, the need for a USB monitor for debugging purposes appeared. During inspection of the QEMU core USB code, I noticed that it only processed control commands for EP0. Other endpoints would be treated as data. There are some virtual devices (host-libusb) that always reject control transfers for those other endpoints. Hence the question whether this is the correct behavior or not (and if valid, whether there exist devices that really implement this).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, there is no use for a non-EP0 control endpoint.  I have developed several products that use custom control transfers on endpoint 0 as the main way to send device-specific requests and I have not encountered any fundamental problems with doing that.

If you did make a non-EP0 control endpoint I think your understanding is correct; you wouldn't be able to use it for standard requests but you would be able to use it for custom requests and the transaction sequences would be the same as on EP0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware that vendor-specific control transfers are also valid for EP0. Do you know examples of devices that have a control endpoint at endpoints other than EP0? I have added some background information to the question, perhaps my concern becomes more clear then.